# Round a number to nearest 100 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I round down number nearest 100 with dart? e.g;

```
43 -> 100
153 -> 200
123 -> 200
450 -> 500
399 -> 400
1234 -> 1300
3456 -> 3500
```

Comment: Your example doesn't round to the nearest hundred; otherwise 43 would round to 0, 123 would round to 100, etc.  You specifically want to round *up* to the next hundred.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int calculateNumber(int number) {
  int a = number % 100;
  
  if (a > 0) {
    return (number ~/ 100) * 100 + 100;
  }
  
  return number;
}
```

Comment: why not `number + (100 - number % 100)`? no need for division and multiplication, for example for number = 123 it would be 123 + (100  - 23) == 123 + 77 == 200

Comment: try number = 100 it would be 100 + (100 - 100 % 100) == 100 + 100 == 200.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1**

Can Use integer division, which truncates the decimal portion of the quotient.

```
int result = ((number + 99) / 100 ) * 100;
```

**Approach 2**

```
(int) (Math.ceil(number/100.0))*100
```